# Executing execvp() in Child process after fork() still taking over parent process?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, fork

I'm executing two bash command `ps` (which is valid bash command to show processes info) and `abc` (Invalid bash command) using `execvp()` inside a child process after creating it with by `fork()`

The problem is once `execvp()` fails parent process is taken over by child process as we can from the output of screenshot.

I had to type *exit* twice to exit out of infinite while loop. What's happening? I'm correctly executing `execvp()` inside a child process yet main(parent) process is taken over by child process?

Can anyone explain this behaviour & how I can fix this ? If `execvp()` fails I do not want that child process to take over parent process. How to handle this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>


int ExecCommand(char** args)
{
    int childId = fork();
    if(childId<0) printf("Error creating child process\n");

    if(childId==0)
    {
        printf("Executing (%s) whose childId:%d\n", args[0], getpid());
        int status=execvp(args[0],args);
        printf("Failed executing %s with status %d whose childId:%d\n\n",args[0],status,getpid());
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int id=wait(NULL);
        printf("waiting for child: %d\n\n",id);
    }
}

int main()
{

    char out[5]="exit\0";
                
    while(1)
    {
        printf("From Main(): pid:%d ppid:%d\n",getpid(), getppid());

        printf("Enter 'exit' to exit or Just hit Enter to execute below 2 commands:");
        char input[25]={'\0'};
        scanf("%24[^\n]",&input[0]);
        getchar();//to remove \n from stdin

        strncpy(out,input,4);
        if(strcmp(out,"exit\0")==0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        char *cmd1[2] = {"ps", NULL}; //valid bash command
        char *cmd2[2] = {"abc", NULL}; //invalid bash command

        char** commands[2]={cmd1, cmd2};
        
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            ExecCommand(commands[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

***Output:***

[image: Output of the program after execution]

Comment: On an unrelated note, the string `"exit\0"` is really *six* characters: The four in the word `exit`, your null-terminator, and the null-terminator added by the compiler. Whom- or what-ever taught you to add your own null-terminator in strings was wrong. And you even use it inconsistently, why do you add an explicit null-terminator for some strings, but not for others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if `execvp` fails, you return to the `main` function in your child process. That leads to both the original (parent) and child process will continue in the loop.

If `execvp` fails you should probably call `exit` to exit the child process.

---

Also note that in the parent process the `ExecCommand` function doesn't return anything at all. If your compiler doesn't complain about that you need to enable more warnings when building.

Comment: I'm waiting for child process to complete in else-block right why does it take over parent? shouldn't it end itself? Can you point me something more on this subject for reading. I recently learned multi-process programming using fork() in c. Not sure completely about it.

Comment: @MudassirHussain In the `ExecCommand` function you do `return 1;` in the child process path. That returns from the `ExecCommand` function, it doesn't exit the process. You should exit from the process instead, by calling `exit(1)` (for example).

Comment: Ok just used exit(1) and its working. Thanks. Will accept the answer.